# Select row by id except a variable number from the end

Tags: mysql

I have got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_list_messages` (
`id`                BIGINT(15)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id`           BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`message`           TEXT                        NOT NULL,
`ticket_id`         BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`ip_address`        VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
`created_time`      DATETIME                    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20;
```

and I select the rows (for the first time only) with this query:

```
SELECT `user_id`,`message`,`created_time` 
FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." 
WHERE `ticket_id`=? 
ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 10
```

and that's fine, but after I call a AJAX script that retrive other rows, the function sends to the PHP script some information and between them there is also a var (offset) that is incremented each time I have a positive response from the server.
The problem is that I want to show the records from the newest to the oldest and I don't know how to exlcude from the query the "last row-the offest":

```
$query = "SELECT `user_id`,`message`,`created_time` 
FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." 
WHERE ticket_id=? AND 'last row'-".$offset.") 
ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers;
```

I thought something like this but obviously it's wrong (Unfortunately I don't know very much mysql):

```
"SELECT `user_id`,`message`,`created_time` 
FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." 
WHERE ticket_id=? 
ORDER BY created_time DESC 
LIMIT 
((SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." 
WHERE ticket_id=?)-".$offset."),".$postnumbers;
```

`$postnumbers` is equal to 10 and the first value of `$offset` is 21 that will be incremented of 10 after each successfull call

These are the records:

```
 id,user_id,message,ticket_id,ip address, created_time
    (1, 55, '&lt;p&gt;ciao ciao&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;ciao&lt;/p&gt; ', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-15 06:26:01'),
    (2, 55, '&lt;p&gt;ciao ciao&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;ciao&lt;/p&gt; ', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 09:29:43'),
    (3, 55, '1', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:06:01'),
    (4, 55, '2', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:07:01'),
    (5, 55, '3', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:08:01'),
    (6, 55, '4', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:09:01'),
    (7, 55, '9', 49, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:14:01'),
    (8, 55, '5', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:10:01'),
    (9, 55, '6', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:11:01'),
    (10, 55, '7', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:12:01'),
    (11, 55, '8', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:13:01'),
    (12, 55, '9', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:14:01'),
    (13, 55, '9', 49, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:14:01'),
    (14, 55, '10', 41, '127.0.0.1', '2013-05-16 17:15:01');
```

with the first run I will select the ids 14 and 12 to 3 except for 7(different ticket id) and with the second query I want to select the id 1 and 2
Probably the easiest solution is to retrive `$postnumbers*number of calls` and then to a `while` loop for only ten of them, but I don't think it will be very efficent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but to get for example the next 10

```
SELECT `user_id`,`message`,`created_time` 
FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." 
WHERE `ticket_id`=? 
ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 11, 10
```

Comment: Sorry, but it will not work, the last inserted record(that will be the first for what I want) is newest and the first is the oldest, so when I run for the first time the query it will select the last ten records from the table and the second time it will exclude this ten records that correspond to the last ten rows with that ticket id

Comment: Your rows are in "descending created_time" order. Newest ones at the top. So what you are looking for is first run 0-9, second run 10-19 and so on. If you can use a variable to keep track of the finished runs, you can do things like `LIMIT ".$runsFinished*10.",10" `